# Use ISO9660 USB for booting

Tags: grub2, grub, kernel-parameters

I'm trying to boot from a USB drive that has an ISO file `dd`'d onto it with `dd if=file.iso of=/dev/sdb`. The ISO file was created using `grub2-mkrescue`, and it boots about half the time if I specify `root=/dev/sda` in the kernel command line arguments, but the rest of the time I can see the USB drive gets assigned `/dev/sdb` in the initrd phase, and the boot fails.

I know the standard way around this is to use `root=LABEL=...` or `root=UUID=...`. However looking in `/dev/disk/by-uuid` or `/dev/disk/by-label`, I see those only point to `/dev/sd?1`, and attempting to mount that fails, whether I do it using `mount` from within the emergency initrd shell or when passing it as a command line.

How can I get the system to persistently mount an ISO9660-format USB drive as the root directory at boot time?

Comment: Just for clarification, is the iso9660 filesystem directly on the disk or partition?

Comment: @OskarSkog `dd`'d directly to the disk; I'll make that explicit in the question.